# $L^p$ is not a normed vector space but $L^p/ \sim$ is.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,A, \mu)$ be a measure space. For $0<p\leq \infty$ define 
$$
L^p(X, \mu) = \{f: X \to \mathbb{F}: f \ \mu \text{-measureable}, \ \|f \|_p < \infty \}
$$
Introduce an eq.relation $\sim$ where, $f \sim g$ iff $f=g$ a.e, $f,g \in L^p.$
Demonstrate that for $1\leq p \leq \infty$ the space $(L^p(X,\mu), \|\cdot \|_p)$ is in general not a normed vector space, but the space $(L^p/\sim, \|\cdot \|)$ is.

So I need to find $f \in L^p$ where one of the properties of the norm fail. Any hint one how I can find such an $f$? Also, it would be helpful if someone could explain a little about the differences of the spaces. As I have understood it, in $L^p$ we can have two elements $f,g$ such that $f=g$ a.e but they are considerd **"different"** elements. But in $L^p/\sim$ if $f=g$ a.e, then $f,g$ would be in the same eq. class and be considerd **"the same"**.

Comment: Does it help if I tell you that $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_p$ is always a _seminorm_ on $L^p$?

Comment: So if $\| f \|_p = 0 \not \Leftrightarrow f = 0$? @DanielFischer

Comment: For some measures it does, but not in general.

Comment: Hmm yes, so if $X = \mathbb{R}$, $p=1$, and $d \mu = dt$ and $f(t) = \sin(x)\cdot 1_{[-\pi, \pi]}$ then $\|f\|_p = 0$ but $f(t) \not = 0$. @DanielFischer

Comment: No, don't forget that we take the modulus, $$\lVert f\rVert_p^p = \int \lvert f\rvert^p\,d\mu.$$

Comment: I wrote $p=1$ not the best example, but to get something to start with. @DanielFischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already wrote down the answer. The thing is if $\|f\|=0$ so $f$ must be $0$ (axiom of a norm). But all $f$ that satisfy $f = 0$ a.e. but don't satisfy $f = 0$ (for example $1_{\{0\}}$ in the case of $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure) also satisfy $\|f\|=0$.

$$1_{\{0\}}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{2}1 & \text{if } x=0 \\
0 &\text{else}
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: And in $L^p/\sim$ we would have $1_{\{0\}} = 0$ a.e!

Comment: The elements of $L^p\backslash\tilde$ aren't functions anymore. The elements are equivalence classes of functions. And $[0]_\tilde$ is the same class as  $[1_{\{0\}}]_\tilde$.

Comment: Yes exactly, now I understand.